# $k$-connected graphs containing trees

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness, trees

I've encountered the following problem in the book "Graphs and Digraphs" and I'm not sure how to do it.

Show that every $k$-connected graph contains any tree of order $k+1$ as a subgraph.

Comment: Try proving it first for small $k$, say $k=1$ and $k=2$. This might give you some ideas. For general $k$, you probably want to use induction.

Comment: Arbitrarily choose a basepoint of the tree and a basepoint of the graph, and then start embedding the tree in the graph in an arbitrary way (i.e., you just start drawing the tree inside the graph).  I guess the $k$-connectedness means you can't get stuck (eg, you certainly don't get stuck at the first step, because each vertex of the graph has degree at least $k$).

Comment: How can I do this for $k=1$? When $G$ is $1$-connected we know that $G$ is connected with order at least $2$ and $G$ has a cut-vertex. Thus since the order of $G$ is at least $2$ and $G$ is connected we know that $G$ contains a tree of order $2$ as a subgraph?

Comment: $k=1$ might be a bit degenerate, but a tree of order 2 is just two distinct vertices connected by an edge, so most graphs do have it as a subgraph.  Maybe you're supposed to exclude loops and multiple edges, and perhaps a single vertex by itself doesn't count as connected?  For $k=2$, it's saying you can find three distinct vertices lying on a path of length 2, which is true (again, provided we exclude multiple edges).

Answer (score 1):

As already stated by Yuval, induction works fine.

We use induction on $k$.
Remember that $k$-connectedness requires $k+1$ vertices and that (by convention and/or
by a suitable choice of the definition of $k$-connectedness) $K_n$ is $n-1$-connected.

Induction base ($k=1$): $G$ is connected and has more than one vertex, so it has an edge.
This means that it embeds the one and only tree on 2 vertices.
(Note that we can even allow $k=0$, provided we do not allow empty graphs or at least
define the empty graph to be not $0$-connected).

Induction step: $k>1$ and the statement proven for smaller values.
Let $T$ be a tree of order $k+1$. Since $k>1$ $T$ has a leaf $v$. Let $u$ be its neighbour.
We can embed $T-v$ in $G$ by the induction hypothesis.
Let $f:T-v\rightarrow G$ be the embedding.

$T-v$ has only $k$ vertices, so it has only $k-1$ vertices different from $u$.
Since $f(u)$ has $k$ neighbours (because $G$ is $k$-connected) it has at least one
`free' neighbour to which we can map $v$.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Two quick questions though. What do you mean when you say embed? Also, how do we know that $T-v$ is in $G$ by the induction hypothesis? Isn't it that we know that $T-v$ is in $G'$ by the induction hypothesis where $G'$ is $(k-1)$-connected?

Comment: A graph $T$ can be embedded in a graph $G$ if $T$ can be identified with a subgraph of $G$. Your second question: no, I really meant embedded in $G$: since $G$ is $k$-connected, it is certainly $k-1$-connected, so it embeds $T$ according to the induction hypothesis.